# XSL - getting a specific item from a list

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML structure:

```
<itemsWithLabels>
    <itemLabelValue>
        <label>A</label>
        <value>a</value>
    </itemLabelValue>
    <itemLabelValue>
        <label>B</label>
        <value>b</value>
    </itemLabelValue>
    <itemLabelValue>
        <label>C</label>
        <value>c</value>
    </itemLabelValue>    
</itemsWithLabels>
```

Using XSL I want to be able to get the value from `<value>` by knowing the label in `<label>`.

So my transformation looks like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$content/itemsWithLabels/itemLabelValue/value[@label='A']" />
```

But clearly something is wrong because I don't have any output.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$content/itemsWithLabels/itemLabelValue[label='A']/value" />
```

`$content/itemsWithLabels/itemLabelValue[label='A']` gets `itemLabelValue` elements with a label element child having value `A`.  The `/value` part gets the child `value` element.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the right approach. Thank you.